# Select with grouping in range

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

```
From Table
A   B
_______________
1   A
3   B
6   C
7   C
8   X   
9   Y
15  Z
16  R
17  t   
23  T
43  e
```

How to bring this result:

```
Range A  Count B
_________________
1-10    6
11-20   3
21-30   1
31-40   1
```

This could be done using loop:

```
Select Count (* ) from TableA where b between @a and @b
```

But I would like to do it without using any loop is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
Cast(((A / 10) * 10 + 1) as varchar(100)) + '-' + Cast(((A / 10) * 10 + 10) as varchar(100)) AS 'Range A',
Count(*) as 'Count B'
 FROM TableA
GROUP BY A / 10
```

Comment: -1, You are using mod, you should be using integer divide `round((a / 10)+/- 0.5)` instead.

Comment: @Johan Yep, well spotted. Fixed.

Comment: The result was not in range 1-10,11-20 as expected but as 1-10,2-11 etc each of lower and upper limit was incremented by 1, so yet to figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Thunder Tested with SQL Server (not SQLite but can't see why it would be different). Works for me - gives 
1-10, 6 | 
11-20, 3 |
21-30,  1 |
41-50, 1

Comment: @Tim Rogers: One reason why ("it would be different") is SQLite might not use integer division in case both operands are integers, like SQL Server does.

Comment: `9` and `10` would be in different groups with this approach: `9 / 10 -> 0`, `10 / 10 -> 1`. Test your query again on the original sample but with `9` changed to `10`, and you'll see.